# (Hard Question) Calculate Number Of Vectors

Tags: calculus, probability, combinatorics, combinations

What is the number of vectors of 4 where each digit is from 0 to 9 (10 possibilities) and X is the maximum digit?

I tried the following:

X is the maximum then once for sure is equal for X
Then the rest have X+1 possibilities, So in total I have: X*(X+1)^3 but that won't work.

Why? because using this method I am calculating duplicates

Any idea on how to solve this please?

Comment: How many are there where $X$ occurs exactly once?  Exactly twice? and so on

Comment: Hint:  it is easier to compute the number of such strings where the max is $≤X$.  You can then get what you want by subtraction.

Comment: Find the number of "vectors" (quadruplets, I assume) where the maximum digit is $\le X$, then take away the number of "vectors" where the maximum digit is $\le (X-1)$

Comment: @Lulu can you kindly write short answer using this method, it's interesting

Answer (score 1):

The number of $k$-vectors where each element is an integer from $1$ to $n$ – i.e. the maximum is *at most* $n$ – is $n^k$. Thus the number of the same but with maximum *exactly* $n$ is $n^k-(n-1)^k$.

Comment: Can you kindly explain what came after "Thus"?